# Stripping path prefix in nginx vs in the nodejs app

Tags: node.js, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

The external URL of my API is something like:

`https://example.com/api/v1/app-prefix/controller-prefix/resource`

What are **pros and cons** of "consuming" (rewriting) the `/api/v1` part in nginx (acting as a proxy) before sending the request to the node.js app, vs. passing the path as-is and letting the app deal with `/api/v1`?

Answer (score 0):

Pros :

- You can have another backend registered behind another path like /api/v2 without updating the NodeJS app.
- The NodeJS app does not need to be aware of which prefix it should use

I don't see any big cons, maybe performances, but this should be benchmarked to check if nginx is bringing an overhead.